# Django webservice for POST data

Tags: django, post

I'm trying to create a web service in Django. For some reason it is working in a GET request but not as a POST (which is my requirement). I have the below url:

```
url(r'^rest/user/(.*)/(.*)/$', 'rest.views.user.user')
```

So if the user was to send a message to `/rest/user/ANY_CHARACTER/ANY_CHARACTER/`, it will go to the below function:

```
def user(request, string1, string2):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return HttpResponse(string1 +  ' ' + string2)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('error')
```

Everytime I send a GET request, i'm getting `error` (which is correct), but everytime I send the same URL as POST, i'm getting HTTP 500 error. Is there something i'm missing here?

**EDIT**

The error log in the terminal has the following:
`[02/Jul/2012 19:13:57] "POST /rest/user/hi/hi HTTP/1.1" 500 61994`

However, when I send the same command as GET, I'm not getting any errors...which is very strange.

**EDIT 1**

I'm noticing the below error when I send a POST request, it works on all other types:

```
<p>Reason given for failure:</p>
<pre>
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
</pre>


<p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when
<a href='http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ref-contrib-csrf'>Django's
CSRF mechanism</a> has not been used correctly.  For POST forms, you need to
ensure:</p>
```

My question is...how do I handle this for webservice requests? Sorry, tried searching for this, but is there a way to get around CSRF for RESTful webservice requests?

Comment: I seen this happen before for a similar situation...it was asking for CSRF protection in POST, does it work only in GET or anything other than POST? (i.e. GET, PUT, etc.)

Comment: Yeah..I just tried PUT and it worked. The message i'm getting back from POST does say CSRF...just noticed that. I'll edit the error.

Comment: ... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, csrf_protect

@csrf_exempt
def user(request, string1, string2):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return HttpResponse(string1 +  ' ' + string2)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('error')
```

I should add that `csrf_exempt` is probably not safe...but will work.